# Masterpage width

Tags: asp.net

I have a question for you. In my asp page, the contentplaceholder is too narrow. I created a table with width="100%" but it still narrow. How can I expand it so then it can cover the whole page. I am not allowed to edit the masterpage.

Comment: can you post html of master page and content page?

Comment: Show actual markup and CSS. A table with a width of 100% will only be 100% of the parent's size, so what is the size of the parent container?

Comment: why dont you make the width of contentplaceholder 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FireBug extension to FireFox or Chrome to see what the table is contained in, and check the width of that. Use CSS to set the width, rather than the width attribute.

```
<table style="width: 100%"> ... </table>
```

n.b. it would be better to add a class or id to the table and use an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change its parents width to 100% you may use left and right properties in CSS.